# A certain zeta function; or, the determinant of the Laplacian plus a constant on the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I am interested in a certain "zeta function," a meromorphic function of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ that depends on a real parameter $\alpha \neq 0$. It's defined for the real part of $s$ large by
$$ \zeta_\alpha(s) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k^2 + \alpha^2)^{-s} $$
I think it has a meromorphic extension that is analytic at $s=0$. My question is:

> What is $\zeta_\alpha'(0)$?

My interest in this question is that $\zeta_\alpha'(0)$ is the determinant of the operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \alpha^2$ on the circle, but I think the question makes independent of this context.

My apologies, because I'm sure the answer is well-known, so a pointer to a reference would be great (in fact, I'm sure I've seen it somewhere, but I can't find it now).

Edit: As I was writing this question, I found the [Wikipedia article on functional determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant), which discusses this problem. But I thought I would ask the question anyway, to see if anyone has a better reference, or any other insight into this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to look is the book "Zeta Regularization Techniques with Applications" by Eliazade et. al. There are some other books by Eliazade, which I think you might find useful.

The calculation you want is fairly straightforward. If it will help, I will sketch how to do it later.

Comment: Have you performed this calculation?  If so, what is the result?